# Outputting multiple datasets from SAS into one excel output with multiple spreadsheets

Tags: sas

Hello I have this program but needed to output pat1, dm1, ie1 etc into one excel output but with each dataset in a separate excel spreadsheet. Would ODS output be able to do this?. In the below example I'm using a preprogrammed macro but only works for one dataset and not for more than one. I would really appreciate any input on this as I'm working over my holidays here and would just like to get this over and done with

```
      *****************************************************************************
Date Created: 23-AUG-2020
Program: dsn2xlsmlti.sas
***************************************************************************
;
OPTIONS NOCENTER VALIDVARNAME=UPCASE;

%let pgm_path = %sysfunc(IFC(%symexist(pgm_path),%nrstr(&pgm_path),%sysfunc(dequote(&_sasprogramfile)))) ;
%put pgm_path=&pgm_path.;
%put pgm_path=&pgm_path;
%let curdir=&pgm_path/..;
%put curdir=&curdir.;

libname here "&pgm_path/../";

* Modify the following two lines to point to the source and target directories.;
%LET SOURC=&curdir./../../sas_data;
%LET TARGET=&curdir.;

* *** LMG2 27-JAN-2017 Assign default spreadsheet name.  Can be manually assigned below.;
%let studyno = %scan(&curdir.,7,/);
%LET SSNAME=&STUDYNO._&SYSDATE9.;
%put ssname=&ssname;
FILENAME LOGFILE "&curdir./DSN2EXCELXP.LOG" TERMSTR=CRLF;
FILENAME LSTFILE "&curdir./DSN2EXCELXP.LST" TERMSTR=CRLF;

PROC PRINTTO LOG=LOGFILE FILE=LSTFILE NEW;
RUN;

ODS RESULTS = OFF;

* Change curdir below, for SAS dataset not in current directory.;
LIBNAME SOURC "&SOURC.";

%include "/mnt/disk3/SAS/development/templates/stat/macros/cleaneg.sas";
%include "/mnt/disk3/SAS/development/templates/dm/macros/makedir.mac";

* Make target folder;
%makedir(&target);
LIBNAME TARGET "&TARGET.";




data pat1;
    set SOURC.pat;
    retain stno subjid PTENRL PTDROP;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid PTENRL PTDROP;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;



data visit1;
    set SOURC.visit;
    retain stno subjid visitn visdat vistnd;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol stno stname usubjid visitn visdat vistnd;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data dm1;
    set SOURC.dm;
    retain stno subjid BRTHDAT SEX ETHNIC RACE RACEOTH;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    raceoth=upcase(raceoth);
    keep protocol usubjid BRTHDAT SEX ETHNIC RACE RACEOTH;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data ie1;
    set SOURC.ie;
    retain stno subjid ieyn;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid ieyn;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data lab1;
    set SOURC.lab_tdl_cs;
    retain stno subjid visitn lbdat lbtim lbcat lbtestcd lborres lborresu lbornrlo lbornrhi  ABNRML lbcom ;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn lbdat lbtim lbcat lbtestcd lborres lborresu lbornrlo lbornrhi  ABNRML lbcom;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data mh1;
    set SOURC.mh;
    retain stno subjid mhyn category mhbody mhterm mhstdat mhongo mhendat ;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid mhyn category mhbody mhterm mhstdat mhongo mhendat;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data spiro1;
    set SOURC.spiro;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt lbdat3 lbtim3 lbstyhr spiroyn prebronc fvc fev1 fevpred fevfvcr spirocom ;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt lbdat3 lbtim3 lbstyhr spiroyn prebronc fvc fev1 fevpred fevfvcr spirocom;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data feno1;
    set SOURC.feno;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt fenotm studyhr fenoppb fenoacc;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt fenotim studyhr fenoppb fenoacc;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data tb1;
    set SOURC.tb;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt tobyn product tobspfy tobnum tbdat tbedat;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt tobyn product tobspfy tobnum tbdat tbedat;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data bsc1;
    set SOURC.BSC;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt bscyn pknd bssdyhr bscdat bsctim pkcomm;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt bscyn pknd bssdyhr bscdat bsctim pkcomm;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data aeyn1;
    set SOURC.aeyn;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt aeyn aeterm;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt aeyn aeterm;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data cmyn;
    merge SOURC.cmyn;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt cmyn cmtrt;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt cmyn cmtrt;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

proc sort;
by subjid; 

data cm;
    merge SOURC.cm;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt cmtrt;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt cmtrt;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

proc sort;
by subjid;

data cmyn1;
merge cmyn cm;
by subjid;
run;

data bronc1;
    set SOURC.bronc;
    retain stno subjid visitn visitno visitdt broncyn BRCONDAT BRONCTIM BRONCBAL BRONTURB BRONVOLB BRONVBF BRONBTIM BRONBCOL BRONLCNT BRONVL BRONLVP BRONCNUM BRONCYTO BRONCTYN BRONNEUT
BRONEOS BRONMACR BRONLRAW BRONEPI;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid visitn visitno visitdt broncyn BRCONDAT BRONCTIM BRONCBAL BRONTURB BRONVOLB BRONVBF BRONBTIM BRONBCOL BRONLCNT BRONVL BRONLVP BRONCNUM BRONCYTO BRONCTYN BRONNEUT
BRONEOS BRONMACR BRONLRAW BRONEPI;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

data acq1;
    set SOURC.acq;
    retain stno subjid acqyn acqdat acqscore;
    protocol= "0175";
    usubjid= "0175" || strip(stno)|| strip(subjid);
    keep protocol usubjid acqyn acqdat acqscore;
    rename usubjid= subjid;
run;

ods excel file='myfile.xlsx';
proc print data=pat1; run;
proc print data=visit1; run;
proc print data=dm1; run;
proc print data=lab1; run;
proc print data=mh1; run;
proc print data=spiro1; run;
proc print data=feno1; run;
proc print data=tb1; run;
proc print data=bsc1; run;
proc print data=aeyn1; run;
proc print data=cmyn1; run;
proc print data=bronc1; run;
proc print data=acq1; run;


ods excel close;


proc printto;
run;

FILENAME LOGFILE CLEAR ;
FILENAME LSTFILE CLEAR ;
LIBNAME SOURC CLEAR ;
LIBNAME TARGET CLEAR ;

TITLE1; FOOTNOTE1;

ODS RESULTS = ON ;
```

Comment: What does the macro do? Is it using the EXCELXP destination to write XML files like the macro name in the commented code implies? Or is it using ODS EXCEL destination to write actual XLSX files?

Comment: It is writing actual XLSX files. The coded out code is a  different macro that does what I want but only dumps out the source data and not the specific variables from the data steps if that makes sense

Comment: @tom is there a simple way of doing this or would you have to create a custom macro?. Only other alternative would be to extract and manually combine excel sheets but would like to find a better approach

Comment: Run the following to get your SAS version : `proc product_status;run;` the answer will be in the log, something like SAS 9.4M5. You need SAS 9.4M3+ to use ODS EXCEL.

Comment: Thank you it's 9.4_M4 so why is it not outputting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open the ODS EXCEL destination at the beginning.  Dump each dataset using your preferred procedure (proc print, proc report,...). Then close it.  There are options to control when a new sheet is started, but the default is for each new procedure to make a new sheet.  There are also options to let you control the names of the sheets.

```
ods excel file='myfile.xlsx';
ods excel options(sheet_name="PAT1");
proc print data=pat1; run;
ods excel options(sheet_name="DM1");
proc print data=dm1; run;
...
ods excel close;
```

Comment: Hi,@ tom thanks for this. I've cleaned my program up a bit and updated in the original question. I'm not familiar with ODS excel but if I can just get it outputting then I can take a look at the options to modify..I just need help as to why it is not outputting?

Comment: The EXCELXP tagsets would work, but why generate an XML file instead of a real XSLX file?  Unless you are running an very old version of SAS you should have ODS EXCEL available.

Comment: There is no SAS 7.1 (or at least no one in their right mind is using it since version 7 was quickly replace by version 8.)  A SAS version number should be something like 9.4m6 .That might be the version for the user interface (SAS/Studio or Enterprise GUIDE) you are using.

Comment: sorry, I rushed that last message its version 9.4 Enterprise Guide

Comment: got it it should be this

Comment: ods excel file="%sysfunc(pathname(work))/myfile.xlsx";
ods excel options(sheet_name="PAT");
proc print data=pat1; run;
ods excel options(sheet_name="VISIT");
proc print data=visit1; run;

ods excel close;